# A question on $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ in algebraic geometry (from Kempf's textbook).

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need some help with question $1.3.5$ below.

Thus far I know that we have an isomorphism between $k[\operatorname{Spec} \ A] $ and $A$, but I do not know how to use it here to prove that there's an induced isomorphism.

Your help is very much appreciated.

[image]